# Need to delete from multiple JLists instead of just the one

Tags: java, database

I have 3 jlists. I have a button that is used to delete a selected item from the Patient Jlist but I also need it to delete from my history Jlist and Invoices Jlist. I have it deleting from one but I dont know how to implement the code to delete from the history jlist and invoices jlist.

Here is my code to delete from 1 JList which works!:

```
JButton btnDeleteDB = new JButton("Delete From DB");
btnDeleteDB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
      int selectedIndex = patientList1.getSelectedIndex();
      if (selectedIndex != -1) { 
         int x = patientList.get(selectedIndex).getID();
         String query =
            "DELETE FROM `patienttable` WHERE `patientid` ='"+x+"' LIMIT 1";
         try {
            Connection con =
               DriverManager.getConnection(
                  "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/denistassignment","root","");
            Statement s = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            s.execute(query);
         } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
         }
         patientListModel.remove(selectedIndex);
         patientList1.remove(selectedIndex);  
      }
   }});
btnDeleteDB.setBounds(320, 500, 125, 23);
contentPane.add(btnDeleteDB);
```

Comment: It would suggest that you create 3 methods. Each one would remove the selected (or related) item. This would provide a cascade or removals, for example, when you call removePatient, it would call removeInvoice and removeHistory as well. This means that you can reuse the functionality as you need, but also maintain the business requirements.

Comment: Removing items from the history and invoice list should be no different then removing an item from the patient list. The problem you might have, is how are these items related?

Comment: I'd also wouldn't be calling patientList1.remove(selectedIndex);  as its not doing what you think it is

Comment: I copied the method for the patientList and changed the basics to delete from the history list but it still doesn't work. I dont have the JLists linked at the moment

Comment: You're going to need to share more code then you are. Also, what's not working? More details are going to be needed before we can accurately deduce your problems

Comment: Dnn't use the setBounds() method to position components. Use Swing the way it was designed to be used and use a proper layout manager. Read the Swing tutorial for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows quite a few design flaws I'm afraid, I will list some before answering your question:

- Remove the code which removes the item from the DB and the list from the ActionListener and place it in a private method so you have easy access to it from other listeners if needed, to enhance readability and to avoid code duplication.
- You are not closing neither the DB connection nor the statement. Do so.
- Don't catch general Exceptions, and don't just call e.printStackTrace() unless for explicit debug code which is removed before production.
- `patientList1.remove(selectedIndex);` has nothing to do with removing an item from the JList, consult the JavaDoc of this method for details. In short, remove that line.

I suppose all your JLists are in the same class and you have member variables pointing to each. If so, then just locate the corresponding objects which should also be removed in your other JLists at the same time you are locating the index of the currently selected one. I don't know the details of your system, so maybe iterate over the other list items, compare IDs with the ID of the one you want to delete and then just call `listXY.getModel().remove(indexOfItem)` for each one you want to delete.